# NetBeans Platform: How to style the Swing based GUI components programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans, netbeans-platform

## Intro

I have to program a fat client using NetBeans Platform and JavaFX 11. One of the requirements is to offer a default and dark theme for the application. So if the user of the application press the dark mode button, the application's GUI has to use the dark theme.

## Problem

While it's obvious to me how to style the JFX components (via a CSS file), the CSS file doesn't have an impact on the NetBeans Platform's components like the menu bar, because they are Swing based. For instance the JavaFX components inside a scene object got a dark styling, but the NetBeans menu bar is still light.

## Question

How its possible to change the style of NetBeans Platform's components programmatically (just as you would have done with CSS in web development or with the CSS support in JavaFX)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an embedded dark LAF in the platform (at least in NB12 which I use) called FlatDarkLaf, it looks nice.

In order to use it, you need to add the following code in the `validate()` method of a `ModuleInstall` subclass, so that it's done very early during the startup process.

```
NbPreferences.root().node("laf").put("laf", "com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf");
UIManager.installLookAndFeel(new UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo("FlatLaf Dark", latDarkLaf.class.getName()));
```

To switch back to the default theme:

```
NbPreferences.root().node("laf").remove("laf");
```

I'm not aware of a (simple) way of changing the LAF without restarting.

For a more complete sample code have a look at my application JJazzLab-X on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab-X), in the `UISettings` Netbeans module.

**EDIT for Netbeans 12.5**

No need to call `installLookAndFeel()`, updating `NbPreferences` is enough.

The module which updates `NbPreferences` should also have a dependency on the **non-API** Netbeans platform module `FlatLaf Look and Feel`.

If your Netbeans platform app uses Netbeans branding (for ex. to customize icon and splash screen), it creates files such as `frame.gif` in your branding directory. But at runtime, if you run a dark theme like FlatDarkLaf, Netbeans will expect the icon to be named `frame_dark.gif`, so you should rename them. See the javadoc of `ImageUtilities.loadImage()` for more information.

Comment: Thanks again. UIManager is what I was looking for. I added the code how I change the LAF at runtime.

Comment: Weird that it's needed as I would except to be done by the FlatLaf module itself:
https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/platform/o.n.swing.laf.flatlaf/src/org/netbeans/swing/laf/flatlaf/Installer.java

Comment: You may want to check that the preference exists before overwriting the existing value: `if (NbPreferences.root().node("laf").get("laf", null) == null) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I add the code fragment that solved my problem:

```java
    private void toggleLookAndFeel() {
        final boolean darkModeEnabled = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName().equals("Flat Dark");
        final String darkLookAndFeel = "com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf";
        final String defaultLookAndFeel = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        try {
            if (darkModeEnabled) {
                // set laf of swing components
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(defaultLookAndFeel);
                // use default css file for javafx components
                this.fxPanel.getScene().getStylesheets().remove(0);
            } else {
                // set laf of swing components
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darkLookAndFeel);
                // use app.css file for javafx components
                this.fxPanel.getScene().getStylesheets().add(0, getClass().getResource("app.css").toExternalForm());
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        triggerSwingComponentUpdate();
    }

    private static void triggerSwingComponentUpdate() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            for (final Window w : Window.getWindows()) {
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(w);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: So this works to change L&F back and forth at runtime?

Comment: Yes, the above code is an on button click action. Each on click changes the L&F. Just set the LAF with UIManager.setLookAndFeel(); and then trigger to rerender all Swing Components with SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI as mentioned in the oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic

Comment: Great I'll try that